# Cannot type unicode in a ubuntu:14.04 container, can type just fine in busybox

Tags: docker

I cannot type unicode characters into an ubuntu:14.04 container, but can do just fine in a busybox container, which is really a surprise because busybox is just 2.4 MB while ubuntu:14.04 is 200+ MB. What is the reason?

Comment: Any lack on this? I have the same issue with greek characters...

Comment: I'm not sure, I switched to CentOS due to this nasty issue

Answer (score 33):

I opened an issue and it turned out that the solution is pretty simple. One needs to run the container with the option:

```
-e LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I have tested with other *UTF-8* variants (such as *en_US.UTF-8* and *el_GR.UTF-8*) but they don't seem to work.

Setting the LANG environment variable in the Dockerfile seems to work as well. Just add the line:

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

I'm still not sure however what's so special about *C.UTF-8* over the other *UTF-8* variants...

Comment: You saved me from a huge headache!

Comment: It is actually caused by. The only default installed locales in official image are `C, C.UTF-8, POSIX`, so other locale obvious won't work at all

Comment: Now I can use special char like as ñ or "México", but I see a letter smaller just in special char case. Could you help me to increase the size?

Comment: Thank you! This should be documented somewhere, but where? Docker docs? I took so long to understand why I couldn't type certain characters. Or maybe this is this basic Linux knowledge I have failed to learn before.

Comment: This is image specific, so it should be part of the image documentation. To be fair, there is now a Locales section in the official Ubuntu image documentation: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

Comment: `LANG` variable is **case sensitive**. `c.UTF-8` does not work, but "`C.UTF-8` does work.